# React - I can't access my public folder when I'm in a route with 2 or more slash. react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I made a component that reads the URL to get an ID and I'm using that ID to show the content the thing is if I use this route the component can't access my public folder.

```
<Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={...} />
```

But if I use this one without the '/' I can access my public folder.

```
<Route path="/menu:dishId" component={...} />
```

[This is my public folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR66r.png)
And this is how I'm accessing my public folder images.

```
image: "img/uthappizza.png",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the Create React App [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) for more details on how to use the public folder.

Below, find a snippet illustration;

```
// Option 1
image: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/uthappizza.png'
// Option 2
image: "/img/uthappizza.png"
```